# What is wrong with this Reversed String code (C)

Tags: c, malloc

This is a code to return a reversed String like "ABC" returns "CBA", but it returns  this "CBA═²²²²ß♣Y*&s".
What is wrong?

```
char* inv(char* C)
{
    int lenght = strLenght(C)-1;
    int idx=0;

    char* tempStr = (char*)malloc(lenght+2);
    for (;lenght>=0;lenght--,idx++)
    {
        tempStr[idx] = C[lenght];
    }
    return tempStr;
}
int strLenght(char* str)
{
    int lenght=0;
    while(str[lenght] != '\0')
        lenght++;
    return lenght;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* st= "ABC";
    char* sr = inv(st);
    printf("%s",sr);
}
```

Comment: I just tried your program on `MinGW` and it works perfectly fine i.e. I observe `CBA` as output.

Comment: @Ganesh You got lucky and had a `'\0'` right next to the string in memory.

Comment: Thank you you should have post in answer that was it, I feel so dumb now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `tempStr` isn't null terminated. Also [strlen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) is a integrated function in c you don't have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments said I was missing the '\0', thank you.

Comment: Armin posted the correct answer before anyone else did.  I think it would be nice to accept his answer and upvote it if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *des, char *src)
{
    int len = strlen(src) + 1;      //strlen() can't calculate the '\0'
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(src) - 1;
         i < len; i++, j--) {
        des[i] = src[j];
    }
    des[i] = '\0';      //important!!
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* st= "ABC";
    char  sr[strlen(st) + 1];
    reverse(sr, st);
    printf("%s",sr);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't fit what I need so I can't use it but the code itself seems good.

Comment: Yes, different API need different algorithm.